# lua Converting strings to numbers

Tags: lua

Converting strings to numbers

```
prise =  "1200$"
print(tonumber( prise))

prise =  "1$20das0$"
print(tonumber( prise))
```

tell me how to get only numbers from a string

Comment: What is the number corresponding to `1$20das0$`? Is it 1.20?

Answer (score 4):

You can use pattern matching.  The pattern `[^%d]` matches everything that is not a digits and we replace it with nothing.

```lua
local prise = "1$20das0$"
local onlydigits = string.gsub(prise, "[^%d]", "")
print(tonumber(onlydigits))
```

[Live example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uEaXWJRKi1tfpHhd)